# Google web fonts and SSL error

Tags: ssl, webfonts

My site is working well with Google webfonts UNTIL the user hits the SSL portion of the site.

At that point, chrome throws the **partial encoding error**, and my cufon menu losses it's kerning.

I'm including my webfont with this css:

```
@font-face {
src: local('Lusitana'), url(https://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/lusitana
/v1/tAIvAkRzqMJf8Y4fM1R7PXYhjbSpvc47ee6xR_80Hnw.woff) format('woff');
}
```

My js console then gives me this error:

> [blocked] The page at https://domain.com/ecommerce.php ran insecure content from 
>   http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lusitana:regular,700&subset=latin.

Any ideas how I can get google fonts to force SSL?

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue too. I've tested with link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gudea" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" and link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gudea" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" but the issue is the same

Answer (score 77):

Have you tried replacing `https://` with `//` in the url? The request should use the correct protocol automatically.

Comment: Simple and effective. Great answer and deserves to be accepted.

Comment: It seems that loading fonts over HTTP is no longer supported, I can only get fonts to load over HTTPS in Chrome even if the entire site is HTTP only.

Comment: Also check if any cache invalidating headers are possibly returned by the server; IExplorer doesn't cope well with it and will not show fonts: [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43094126/1767316)

Answer (score 4):

locate this line on your HTML page (or template):

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

and change it to this:

```
 <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

This simple change will make your browser call the Google Font page in the applicable mode (HTTP vs HTTPS).

Enjoy!

Comment: I was not able to use // in chrome v49 (non https local page).. https worked however. Google recommends using https on all these calls, and it is probably best to stick with https:// for a few reasons

Comment: Any citations for those claims?

Answer (score 3):

To load google fonts that will work in non-secure, and SSL mode, try the following in your page header - (and remove what you've got there calling a https:// inside the CSS):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  WebFontConfig = { google: { families: [ 'Droid+Serif::latin' ] } };
  (function() {
  var wf = document.createElement('script');
  wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
    '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
  wf.type = 'text/javascript';
  wf.async = 'true';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
})();
</script>
```

In my example, I'm using Droid Serif font, so swap that with yours.

[You can read more on this here.](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/webfont_loader)

Comment: See @londonium's answer below for a much simpler solution which works and is valid.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this error caused by a theme in WordPress. It caused slow page loading and the following error reported by development console:

*Mixed Content: The page at 'https://xxxxxxx.co.uk/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?
family=Droid+Serif%3A400%2C700%2C400italic%2C700italic&ver=5.4.1'. This
request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.*

The culprit was Wordpress theme called "Fresh and Clean".  It inherits code written in 2014 which contains 'pre-SSL' coding practices

To resolve the problem all need to do is make changes inside the following file in the theme:

**/wp-content/themes/wpex-freshandclean/functions/scripts.php**

Look inside for any occurences of `http://`  and change each one to `https://`