# WebBrowser font-face request abort weirdness

Tags: wpf, internet-explorer, font-face

I've built an WPF application (.NET 4.5) which runs on Win7 IE11 machines. The main window has a webbrowser control on it and nothing else (its a very simplified version of my actual app which is experiencing issues).

On some machines when browsing to a given web site the font-face fonts (WOFF and TTF) are not working, even though they do work in IE11 on the same machine. I have used a reg punch to get the webrowser to run in IE11/ edge mode, this does not fix the issue.

Using Fiddler2 I have seen that the request for the font gets aborted after the whole font was downloaded. Repeating the request with Fiddler works and doesn't get aborted, so I know the issue must be with the webbrowser control.

All the machines affected are on a certain domain. Does anyone know of any permissions at domain/policy level which would cause the font to work in IE but be aborted/rejected in a WPF webbrowser control?

This only happens for fonts delivered over HTTPS

Comment: I've exactly the **same** issue and no solution is in sight. Please can you give an update. Have you solved the problem meanwhile?

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the font download settings in IE, as illustrated here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We have fixed this. It is a security (SSL) issue with cached data. You can fix it by setting the following option in internet explorer: See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815313

Answer (score 0):

Check if any cache invalidating headers are possibly returned by the server; IExplorer doesn't cope well with it and will not show fonts: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43094126/1767316)